# Standard SQL for BigQuery - Get number of occurrences in last 1, 7 and 30 days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to have a query result with each column having values showing number of times the entity occurred in last 1, 7 and 30 days.

I have tables like:

document:

```
+-----+---------+-------------------------+
| dId | score   | datetime                |
+-----+---------+-------------------------+
| A   | 100     | 2019-03-08 16:17:34.043 |
| B   | 80      | 2019-02-15 16:17:34.043 |
| C   | 70      | 2019-03-08 16:17:34.043 |
+-----+---------+-------------------------+
```

entity:

```
+------+-----+
| name | dId |
+------+-----+
| e1   |   A |
| e2   |   A |
| e1   |   B |
| e1   |   C |
| e2   |   C |
+------+-----+
```

Expected Output:

```
+------+----+----+------+
| name | 1D | 7D |  30D |
+------+----+----+-------
| e1   | 2  |  2 |   3  |
| e2   | 1  |  1 |   2  |
+------+----+----+------+
```

A simple query to get records from last 30 days is :

```
SELECT * FROM document where datetime >= DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

But how can I join and get count of the records in 1,7,30 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use case expression

```
SELECT e.name,
SUM(CASE WHEN d.datetime>=DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  oneD,
SUM(CASE WHEN d.datetime>=DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sevenD ,
SUM(CASE WHEN d.datetime>=DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS thirtyD
FROM
document d JOIN entity e ON d.did=e.did GROUP BY e.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `COUNTIF()` in BigQuery:

```
SELECT e.name,
       COUNTIF(d.datetime >= DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME, INTERVAL 1 day)) AS day_1,
       COUNTIF(d.datetime >= DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME, INTERVAL 7 day)) AS day_7,
       COUNTIF(d.datetime >= DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME, INTERVAL 30 day)) AS day_30
FROM document d JOIN
     entity e
     ON d.did = e.did
GROUP BY e.name;
```

Although `current_datetime` can be referenced as a function (i.e. with `()`), the parentheses are optional and I don't see any value in using them.

Also, if you are measuring time periods in terms of days, you may not want to include the time component.  If that is the case, you should ask another question.

Comment: Please can you tell the advantage of using COUNTIF over SUM?

Comment: Less typing.  Clearer.  And possibly faster, but the increment in speed would be hard to measure.